# Confusing output with Logical OR?

Tags: javascript

I am using Chrome developer tool to run the program as below. It's logging the expected output to console 3 times(I thought the expected output will be printed only 2 times).

```
if(null||console.log("bpjoshi")||console.log("bpjoshi")||console.log("bpjoshi")){
console.log("bpjoshi");
}
```

It's giving me output 3 times.

```
bpjoshi
bpjoshi
bpjoshi
```

After null if the first condition of OR operator evaluates to true, why it is giving 3 outputs.

If I run the below code

```
var x=5;
if(null||console.log("bpjoshi")||console.log("bpjoshi")||x>6){
    console.log("bpjoshi");
    }
```

It's output is as below

```
bpjoshi
bpjoshi
```

but if I run the if test as below it's giving me output 3 times again.

```
var x=5;
if(null||console.log("bpjoshi")||console.log("bpjoshi")||x>4){
    console.log("bpjoshi");
    }
```

It gives the output as below.

```
bpjoshi
bpjoshi
bpjoshi
```

I am confused,how do I explain this to myself?

[Jsfiddle link for the same](https://jsfiddle.net/bpjoshi/tjbahufd/)

Comment: All of these make sense. `console.log` returns `undefined`, which is not a true value.

Comment: console.log does not evaluate to true (why you would put console.log in a conditional is a separate issue), so you won't run the console.log statement that would occur upon evaluating to true

Comment: Ah! Too bad! Looks like I missed out on something very basic. It indeed returns undefined and that's evaluated to false on doing Boolean(undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these make sense, since `console.log` returns `undefined` (which is not `true`).

```
if (null || console.log("bpjoshi") || console.log("bpjoshi") || console.log("bpjoshi")) {
    console.log("bpjoshi");
}
```

First, `null` is evaluated. This isn't `true`, so we move on. Next `console.log("bpjoshi")` is evaluated. This prints `bpjoshi` to the console and returns `undefined`. Since this isn't `true`, we move on. We log two more `bpjoshi`s. Nothing in our `||` chain returned `true`, so we don't enter the `if` block.

The others are similar. Each time `console.log("bpjoshi")` is evaluated, it logs to the console and returns `undefined`.

```
var x = 5;
if (null || console.log("bpjoshi") || console.log("bpjoshi") || x > 6) {
    console.log("bpjoshi");
}
```

Here, we end up logging twice, because we don't enter the `if` block. (All of the things in our `||` chain are `false`.)

Finally,

```
var x = 5;
if (null || console.log("bpjoshi") || console.log("bpjoshi") || x > 4) {
    console.log("bpjoshi");
}
```

Here we log twice while evaluating the `||` chain, and since `x > 4` is `true`, we move into the `if` block and log once more.

All of this is probably easier to follow if you put different strings in your `console.log` calls.

Answer (score 2):

`||` checks if any of the expression true, it enters the `if`. Since `null` is not `truthy` and console log returns nothing it is also not `truthy`, your only way to enter the `if` is the condition which is based on `x`.

If you give 4 statements in side `if` condition which are `||`, then it keep executing one by one see anything is truthy. If any one is truthy it just stops execting and enters in side.

```
var x=5;
if(null||console.log("bpjoshi")||console.log("bpjoshi")||x>6){
    console.log("bpjoshi");
    }
```

In the above case all the statemets got executed and is `x>6` is false. So it didn't enter that if.

And

```
var x=5;
if(null||console.log("bpjoshi")||console.log("bpjoshi")||x>4){
    console.log("bpjoshi");
    }
```

In this case all the statements got executed and `x>4` is true, so it entered the if and printed the log inside the if. Hence you seeing 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

This has a truthy condition

```
var x=5;
if(null||console.log("bpjoshi")||console.log("bpjoshi")||x>4){
    console.log("bpjoshi");
    }
```

The others are all falsey conditions

You can see that this is falsey

```
if(console.log("bpjoshi")){
    console.log("bpjoshi");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The really short answer is for every time you wrote `console.log()` inside of your `if` condition, you **will** get that logged to the console. In your first bit of code, you are instructing the environment to write to the `console` 3 times and only a 4th time if the `if` condition can be evaluated to `true`, which it doesn't.

```
if(null||console.log("bpjoshi") || console.log("bpjoshi") || 
   console.log("bpjoshi")){
      console.log("bpjoshi");
}
```

This is not at all how an `if` statement should be written.

An `if` statement checks to see if a condition (provided in parenthesis) is `true`.

```
null is never `true`
console.log("bpjoshi") is executed, but doesn't return a value
console.log("bpjoshi") is executed, but doesn't return a value
console.log("bpjoshi") is executed, but doesn't return a value
```

Since none of those statements return anything that could be `true`, the body of your `if` statement's `true` branch is not entered.

In this code:

```
var x=5;
if(null||console.log("bpjoshi")||console.log("bpjoshi")||x>6){
   console.log("bpjoshi");
}
```

The if statement is again directed to evaluate `null`, which is again, not `true`.

It again says to write to the console twice, and again, neither of those expressions return `true`

And, finally it tests `x` to see if it is less than `6`, which it is, so the `true` branch of your `if` statement is reached and another `console.log("bpjoshi")` is exectued for a 3rd time.

The key to understanding all of this is that `console.log()` is an instruction to write to the `console`. It's not a condition to maybe write to the `console`. If you include those statements in your `if` condition, they **will** be executed and their return value (`undefined`) will be tested against `true`.

In reality, you would never see an expression that is known to never return a value inside of an `if` condition, like your code does because it can never be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

[**Logical OR operator `||`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) will short circuit the result of the LHS if the LHS is *truthy*.

This means `expr1 || expr2` will have the following cases;

- `expr1` invoked - truthy, `expr2` never invoked, *logical or* gives result of `expr1`
- `expr1` invoked - falsy, `expr2` invoked - truthy, *logical or* gives the truthy result of `expr2`
- `expr1` invoked - falsy, `expr2` invoked - falsy, *logical or* gives the falsy result of `expr2`

---

[***Falsy* things**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) act like `false` in conditions

- The *value returned* from a `console.log('foo'); // undefined` is *undefined*, which is *falsy*
- `null` is falsy

---

So,

- `console.log('foo') || console.log('bar'); // undefined`, but logs `"foo"` and `"bar"`
- `null || expr` is equal to just `expr`

---

Ultimately, the meaningful bits of your `if` conditions thus boil down to `5 > 6; // false` or `5 > 4; // true`, but every invoked `console.log` will still show the logged value in the *Console*

Answer (score 1):

When you run this code

```
var x=5;
if(null||console.log("bpjoshi")||console.log("bpjoshi")||x>6){
    console.log("bpjoshi");
}
```

The console is running the console.log("bpjoshi").  console.log() outputs into the console.

So your code (the one above), is testing if null, outputting "bpjoshi" to the console, outputting "bpjoshi" to the console, and testing if x>6.
since null is not true, and console.log just outputs to the console, the only thing being tested is x>6 which is false.  So you would expect only two "bpjoshi" in the console.

I hope this helps.